# Is an app with integration of Aviary free SDK allowed for playstore publishing?

Tags: android, google-play, aviary, adobecreativesdk

i am adding image editor based on Aviary SDK in my android application which is already on playstore. I have searched around be bit but couldn't find any authentic and clear statement about wether Adobe and Google allow the apps with free version of Aviary to be published on playstore. 
Guidance anticipated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason why Google should not allow it.
Adobe wants to review your app before submitting.
Take a look here https://creativesdk.adobe.com/docs/android/#/submissionguidelines/index.html